# Dog goes crazy on leash when he sees other dogs

Tags: dogs, behavior, training, leash-training

I have a Nova Scotia Duck Tolling Retriver that goes everyday of the week to a dog-kindergarden. So the whole day stays with other dogs, plays, sleeps and whatever dogs do there. However, when we are walking on leash and he sees other dog he just pulls at max force thowards that other dog and becomes aggresive.

If he is out of the leash, then he starts to sniff the other dog and in 1-2 minutes he starts to ignore the other dog.

He may have also a leash problem, he likes to be always in front, but he also listens when I say to him on foot, then he stays closer. I plan to follow some instructions from here ([Dog knows to stop on leash but still pulls](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7419/dog-knows-to-stop-on-leash-but-still-pulls)) to improve this behavior.

PS: He has also a problem with skateboarders, I tried to make him confortable with a skateboard by riding one. At the beginning he barked at me, but then started to get used with it. When I went faster, he started to bark again, but I can say that even if now he doesn't have any problem with me riding a skateboard, it's when he sees other people riding that he gets aggresive.

Any advice how can I improve his behavior? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dog can get aggressive on leash because their movement gets limited and start feeling uncomfortable, which makes them attack to protect their space. Which I bet is case, because your dog is fine with other dogs unless he is on leash. I would suggest watching videos like this:

- [Training to Help Calm a Dog Who Barks and Lunges on Leash](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bkAzgqKRyk)
- [How to teach any dog not to bark at other dogs and people on a walk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTmc6fjM_y4)
- [How to Teach ANY Dog to Walk Nicely on Leash!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KuEPBcePu80)
- [How to Train Your Dog to not pull on the Leash!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBN2_YuTclU)
- [How to Get Your Reactive Dog Under Control While on a Walk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRApwBzVD9A)

I can't find video exactly about leash aggression and I didn't watch every video I linked, but they still are relevant both to issue of aggression and if he pulls leash. You will probably need to start from making a dog pay attention to you in spaces he knows without dogs etc and slowly move to bigger more distracting spaces. He can't get aggressive and bark on other dogs if he pays attention to you and not them (Something similar and detailed steps will be in videos I linked).

Also I would advise against using any types of choke/electric collars, because they can harm the dog, and only work when dog has them. Instead positive training makes dog think, and learn how to behave.

And since you go to dog kindergarten, I would also suggest asking for tips instructor there. He should have knowledge and experience about dog issues (but if he suggests stuff I wrote above to not use, you should consider changing instructor).